# HTTPS enable for proxy server or web server

Tags: tls, webserver, apache, nginx

Say I have 2 separated servers which are one web server (apache) and one proxy server (nginx), I want to use HTTPS for the website running on the Apache.

Do I enable SSL on **apache** or **nginx** or **both**?

If enable on both, is it duplicated setup? because my internal network (between apache and nginx) are very secure.

If both using HTTPS, the speed will be affected than only one HTTPS connection (between internet and proxy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common to terminate SSL (ie. decrypt traffic) at the first point where your network receives the traffic assuming your internal network can be considered secure. Often this is at a load balancer or caching proxy.

In your scenario I'd terminate the SSL at nginx.